# MYSQL SELECT помогите

Tags: mysql, sql

Не могу написать корректный sql select запрос. Присутствуют 2 таблицы - garage_items и users_items. В первой хранятся все существующие предметы и их данные(вроде названия, цены, уникальности), во второй хранятся данные о предметах определенного юзера(айди юзера, айди предмета, количество). Нужно вывести ВСЕ существующие предметы, но те, которые принадлежат пользователю пометить переменной is_owned == 1. НО! Если предмет уникален(записано в garage_items, как special == 1) и его НЕТ у пользователя - выводить не нужно, если же он уникален и есть у юзера или не уникален вовсе - выводи.

Comment: Лефт джойн и в качестве  is_owned использовать user_id из users_items. условие отображения написать во where.

Comment: клеите таблицу предметов у пользователя по left join не забыв указать прямо в ON нужного пользователя. После чего в where указываете ваши варианты условий, учитывая тот факт, что если запись для пользователя не нашлась то любые поля второй таблицы будут NULL. Ну и в списке выборки запроса выставляете 1 в is_owned если поле второй таблице не null